# setup.sh syntax error on source

Tags: ros, bash, setup.sh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 on my desktop computer (9th gen intel i5 processor, nvidia gtx 1080 gpu). I followed the instructions to install the Ros 2 Rolling Ubuntu binaries for my system (from this page: https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html). I made it to the Environment setup section. After running `source /opt/ros/rolling/setup.bash` I got the following errors:

`bash: setup.sh: line 59: syntax error near unexpected token }'`

`bash: setup.sh: line 59: }'`

I tried reinstalling everything from the binaries again, restarting my system, and inspecting the `setup.sh` file but was unable to find out what was happening. It doesn't help that I am not very familiar with these kinds of more complicated shell scripts.

In case it matters, here is my setup.sh (sorry for pastebin link, not sure how to do a code block here):
https://pastebin.com/Dr5efb3P

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/408289/setup.sh-syntax-error-on-source/) by [piperdaniel1](https://answers.ros.org/users/121399/piperdaniel1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2022-10-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-10-21**:
I am not sure why `source /opt/ros/rolling/setup.bash` is failing. However, instead of Rolling, can you please try Humble Hawksbill? BTW, which shell are you using? Here is my system:

```
$ echo "$SHELL"
/bin/bash
```

**Comment by [piperdaniel1](https://answers.ros.org/users/121399/piperdaniel1/) on 2022-10-22**:
Thanks for your help! Luckily I figured out the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Alright, I figured it out.

I aliased the word "done" in my .bashrc to a command. As I am not familiar with bash scripting I was not aware that this is a control word in bash. Anyway, there are no warnings when you do this, bash just switches out all of the "done" lines in bash scripts for whatever you aliased. This caused the syntax error to occur, because bash was expecting a for loop to be closed with a done. It reached the bracket before it saw a done (because of the alias) and therefore had an error.

---

Originally posted by [piperdaniel1](https://answers.ros.org/users/121399/piperdaniel1/) with karma: 16 on 2022-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0